# How to pass-through an internal water cooling usb device to wine bottle?

Tags: usb, kubuntu, wine

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 and I was able to install the software NZXT Cam to control my NZXT Kraken Z63, the problem is the software is not detecting a cooling device.

So I was wondering if there is a way to passthrough that USB port to wine to make the cam software recognize it.

I look all over wine website but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

Thank you for any help you can provide,

I tried the liquidctl software but doesn't support the lcd display.

Comment: How to use a USB device in Wine is answered at https://superuser.com/questions/1477796/making-usb-work-in-wine-4-0-ubuntu-19-04